# jquery dropdown menu border issue

Tags: jquery, css

Here's a fiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/8ML3u/

I needed to simulate this kind of dropdown menu (`#topnav`) where the bottom border merges just where the upper menu element is located. I came up with this solution but it just isn't flexible enough, breaks down in different browsers and it doesn't work in IE8 at all. I'm very confused as to how else I can make this kind of menu. What can I do?

Here's what I'm trying to make:
http://i39.tinypic.com/2zghfnt.png

EDIT: Sorry, I might have not made it clear enough, but the menu should be completely transparent and the backgrounds behind it are not static.

Comment: There are hundred of tutos regarding this kind of navigation menu, some using only CSS.

Comment: @roasted can you link some? My native language isn't english and I was confused as to what to type into google, lol. I tried searching but couldn't find anything that suits my needs.

Comment: googl[ize]: **css drop down navigation menu** First link seems not bad: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu If you need more functionalities for the future of your site, i'll suggest you to look at a bootstrap as twitter's one: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: @roasted The thing is, there's nothing about how to merge the border. My main concern is if background changes, it shouldn't affect the border, because if i cover it up by a div, it immediately shows on another colored background. Here, i'll post a pic of what i'm striving to achieve.

Comment: Here's another [tutorial](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/). Yes, the border isn't merged, but you simply adjust that in the CSS (it's a margin or padding value probably)

Comment: @Johannes sorry, but I don't see how adjusting margin or padding would solve my issue and yes, I know how to make a dropdown menu, I already did that. :)

Comment: I don't think you can make this happen with a transparent menu, you would at least need a constant background color to cover the part of the border just below the first level item

Comment: @koala_dev damn it. May be I should cover it up with div and then I should dynamically update its color with js? But if it's an image, it won't work. Damn it again.

Answer (score 2):

I edit this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8ML3u/1/

Now You can see. Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, I used a similar approach to what you had, I dynamically append an element to display the border part that is missing and made it simpler by having most of the style already in CSS and just having to calculate the width:

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#topnav > li').hover(function () {
        if ($(this).children('ul').length > 0) {
            var submenu = $(this).find('ul:first');
            var border = $('<div class="border">').css('width', submenu.width() - $(this).width() + 'px');
            submenu.before(border);
            $(this).css('border-bottom','transparent');
        }
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.border').remove();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.border {
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px grey solid;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    bottom: -1px;
}
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ML3u/5/)**